# What is the fastest way to get currency in Looney Tunes: World of Mayhem?

Tags: looney-tunes-world-of-mayhem

I am trying to rank up one of my toons in **Looney Tunes: World of Mayhem** (Or in short words, LTWOM), and I am having trouble finding ways to get currency. Here is what I tried doing when I used supporting websites:

- **Contacting Support For Tips.**
  The support responded that you should work, work, and work to get currency, and that is what I am doing right now.
- **Microtransactions** 
  I am a free player, so I didn't do anything with this tip.
- **Alliance Discussion.**
  My alliance members seem to not know any other than the common work-hard tips that are used.

  ---

  In all words, can I have tips and/or fast ways I can get gems/currency in LTWOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of the fastest ways you can get more coins/gems/special materials in **the game:** (NOTE: These are free ways.)

1. **Auto-winning battles frequently.** 
   Auto-winning is a faster way to get loot, such as coins, but is a 25% less value than the winning original offer.
2. **The Lucky Saloon.**
   The Lucky Saloon offers multiple rewards, so try to go for a jackpot to get a bigger prize, up to 5000+ coins.
3. **Complete quests in the battle pass.**
   You can get free golden tickets if you have enough war tokens, and can use those golden tickets for tune-up materials for coins.

---

***For gem aquires:***

1. **Daily Challenges**.
   Daily Challenges has up to 300 gems per win, so you can win these battles for them. (Note: Gems cannot be collected by auto-win, one time.)
2. **Inbox Rewards.**
   You can get inbox rewards for gems for either playing the game, or get them daily for playing brawl.
3. **Milestone rewards.**
   Play tournaments and earn points for milestone rewards, up to 200 toon pieces and gems.

   ---

   These were for both coins and gems, the most common currency in the game. Special currency, such as energy, can be obtained **FASTER** through microtransactions or energy bottles, which you do not want to pay, so I wouldn't mention ways for special energy. The only fast and easy free way to get energy little by little is through ACME hourly crates.

75% of the ways you've tried doing to get more currency is contacting other players. If they seem not to know faster ways, you can ask them how you got their currency and/or their toons presently. For support, you can ask for common ways to get coins, so you can get some sort of idea for faster ways, such as Battle Crates.

You are a free player, and free players can get discouraged easily with all the offers in the game. A popular advantage, from the first Google Search I have tried,is from [Cheat On](https://cheat-on.com/looney-tunes-world-of-mayhem), the first website that appeared to me, mentions using hacks, which surprises lots of free players.